# How to get rid of spacing between Bootstrap panels?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### The Problem

[image]

There are spaces between my panels (outlined in red) and I want to get rid of them. I tried doing:

```
.panel {
    margin-top: 0; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    padding-top: 0; 
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

But it didn't work.

For the white space at the very bottom of the page, I tried setting the encompassing `container` and `#Menu` to `margin-bottom: 0`, but that didn't work.

If anyone could let me know how to get rid of the spacing, I would appreciate it very much!

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="panel-group" id="problem-panels">
                <div class="panel panel-default top-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            Cox Substraction Level 1c
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li class="active"><a>11</a></li>
                                <li><a>12</a></li>
                                <li><a>13</a></li>
                                <li><a>14</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
                            Cox Addition Level 3b
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">panel body 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default bottom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">
                            Cox Subtraction Level 2a
                        </h4> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">panel body 3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

*CSS*

```
#problem-panels > .top-panel{
    border-top: none;
}

#problem-panels > .bottom-panel{
    border-bottom: none;
}

/*Get rid of grey border at top of panel body*/
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border: none;
}

#problem-panels {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.panel-title {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.panel-body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/3hrduq3f/1/)

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3hrduq3f/2/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file. It should remove the extra margin.

```
.panel-group .panel + .panel {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Additionally you could also add a class to your panels so that you don't change any other panels by mistake

```
.my-panels{
    margin-top:0!important;
}
```

Also its a good idea to use the browser inspector to see what styles are being applied to which elements.

Happy coding!

Comment: Actually nvm, it worked! I realized I made a typo, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the fiddle that Alex posted

Comment: You're welcome. Also don't forget to mark this as the answer for others. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can override other rules with [important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) flag.

```
.panel {
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#problem-panels .panel-default {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `!important` modifier.

Your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3hrduq3f/5/)

Just be weary that it will modify all your `.panel`s.

I suggest you define a custom class, and use it where you want this modification to take place.